# How to sum values from column B by choosing multiple different values from column A?

Tags: excel-formula

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

I want add number by choosing alphabet, and like if choose A & B in formula then cell must show sum value 3 and even if I shuffle the alphabet upside downside it still show the 3 by analyzing alphabet.

Comment: We need more input to help you, please see [tour]

Comment: You should highlight your table, under `insert` select `PivotTable`. Put the letters in the bottom left box and the values in the bottom right. You can filter and sort however you'd like and get your sum that way without any complicated formulas.

Answer (score 1):

I first checked which of the key values are present in the user-provided input string. I made a new column where I assigned an extra value of 0 to those that are not present in the input string, and a value of 1 to those that are. I then multiplied that binary column with the corresponding value, and then summed them all up.

I started with FIND(), which will tell you where the value of the key letter starts in the input string. E.g., =FIND("A", "BAC") will return 2, because "A" starts in the second position of "BAC".

This will return an error if the string can't be found, so I surrounded the output of the FIND() with IFERROR(). IFERROR takes in an expression and lets you specify what you want the output to be if the expression returns an error. I set the error output value to be '0'.

I then surrounded all of that with an IF() statement. If the value is 0, leave it as 0. If it's greater than 0, set it to be 1.

This IF(IFERROR(FIND())) expression will produce a 0 or a 1 for each key letter, which you can then multiply with that key's value to obtain how much that key contributes to the final sum. And then it can all be added up neatly.

[Screenshot of final spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmS8P.png)

The important cell formulas are:

- C1: (whatever your input string is)
- C2: =SUM(C5:C7)
- A5: A
- A6: B
- A7: C
- B5: 1
- B6: 2
- B7: 3
- C5: =IF(IFERROR(FIND(A5,$C$1),0)>0,1,0)*B5
- C6: =IF(IFERROR(FIND(A6,$C$1),0)>0,1,0)*B6
- C7: =IF(IFERROR(FIND(A7,$C$1),0)>0,1,0)*B7